# How to automatically download C++ dependencies in a cross platform way + CMake?

Tags: c++, windows, dependencies, cmake

Basically I want to achieve this workflow:

1. Checkout from repository on windows system (or any platform for that matter).
2. Run some tool that gets dependencies, both includes and libs and puts them in their proper place (like in "\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Lib and \Includes" on windows)
3. Run CMake (creates MSVS projects on win)
4. Open up MSVS project and compile it.

And i would like to have this workflow on most platforms.

**I dont want to have to download dependencies manually**

How to do this without storing dependencies in repository?
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found any solution to you problem yet? I've been searching for something npm-like for building C/C++ programs with dependencies.

Comment: @hg. there's no cross-platform package manager for C++ as far as I know.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In CMake you can use `file(DOWNLOAD URL PATH)` to [download a file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:file), combine this with custom commands to download and unpack:

```
set(MY_URL "http://...")
set(MY_DOWNLOAD_PATH "path/to/download/to")
set(MY_EXTRACTED_FILE "path/to/extracted/file")

if (NOT EXISTS "${MY_DOWNLOAD_PATH}")
    file(DOWNLOAD "${MY_URL}" "${MY_DOWNLOAD_PATH}")
endif()

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${MY_EXTRACTED_FILE}"
    COMMAND command to unpack
    DEPENDS "${MY_DOWNLOAD_PATH}")
```

Your target should depend on the output from the custom command, then when you run CMake the file will be downloaded, and when you build, extracted and used.

This could all be wrapped up in a macro to make it easier to use.

You could also look at using the CMake module [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:ExternalProject) which may do what you want.

Comment: But this is not a crossplatform way to setup and install the dependencies, neither are the dependencies downloaded from a common repository

Comment: Using CMake `file(DOWNLOAD ...)` or ExternalProject is cross platform. If the dependencies are packages, then on Windows you would need to use `msiexec` for MSI package installation; on Linux, it depends on the distribution: on Red Hat derivatives `yum` or `rpm` with RPM packages, on Debian derivatives `apt` or `dpkg` with DEB packages.

Comment: Yes, the download command is crossplatform, however this is not a crossplatform way to INSTALL dependencies. Each platform usually has different files and packages (and hence download links) for the same dependency. You could say that i'm looking for something like Maven for C++ dependencies that would fit together well with CMake.

Comment: @JBeurer If you actually have to *install* these dependencies beforehand, this might not be such a good idea at all; Rather, just add whatever dependency your software has in the installation instructions, and let the user install it manually. It may not sound so exciting to those who want to automate everything, but it's certainly safer way, and more importantly, it *works*.

Comment: @skyhisi actually, for FILE(DOWNLOAD....  the second parameter is file, so you can't especify a path.

Answer (score 9):

From cmake 3.11 on there is a new feature: [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)

You can use it to get your dependencies during configuration, e.g. get the great [cmake-scripts](https://github.com/StableCoder/cmake-scripts).

```cmake
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  cmake_scripts
  URL https://github.com/StableCoder/cmake-scripts/archive/master.zip)
FetchContent_Populate(cmake_scripts)
message(STATUS "cmake_scripts is available in " ${cmake_scripts_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I prefer fetching the ziped sources instead of directly checking out. But `FetchContent` also allows to define a git repository.

Comment: But it doesn't resolve transitive dependecies automatically

Comment: The linked docs in the first line suggest using FetchContent_MakeAvailable() instead of FetchContent_Populate().

Answer (score 4):

**Within the CMake universe:**

*vcpkg*

[vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) is a package manager for C++ Library Manager for Windows, Linux, and macOS. It can be seamlessly integrated with CMake - see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md) for details.

*Conan*

[Conan](https://conan.io/) is a C/C++ package manager. It also has a [strategy](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html) for the integration with CMake.

*CMake with ExternalProject_Add*

CMakeList.txt.in:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)
```

*example.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

**Outside of the CMake universe:**

I suggest you not to use CMake! Use [Bazel](https://bazel.build/)!

For instance if you want to use [gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest):

*WORKSPACE*

workspace(name = "GTestDemo")

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
    name = "googletest",
    #tag = "release-1.8.1",
    commit = "2fe3bd994b3189899d93f1d5a881e725e046fdc2",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    shallow_since = "1535728917 -0400",
)
```

*BUILD*

```
cc_test(
    name = "tests",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    copts = ["-isystem external/gtest/include"],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],

)
```

*text.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

How to run the test?

```
bazel test //...
```

For instance if you want to use [boost](https://www.boost.org/):

*WORKSPACE*

```
workspace(name = "BoostFilesystemDemo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

# Fetch Boost repo
git_repository(
    name = "com_github_nelhage_rules_boost",
    commit = "49066b7ccafce2609a3d605e3667af3f07e8547c",
    remote = "https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_boost",
    shallow_since = "1559083909 +0200",
)

load("@com_github_nelhage_rules_boost//:boost/boost.bzl", "boost_deps")

boost_deps()
```

*BUILD*

```
cc_binary(
    name = "FilesystemTest",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    defines = ["BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB"],
    deps = [
        "@boost//:filesystem",
    ],
)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

How to build:

```
bazel build //...
```

How to run:

```
bazel run //:FilesystemTest
```

If you want to generate a Visual Studio solution use [lavender](https://github.com/tmandry/lavender). Unfortunately lavender is only experimental and it needs some improvement. But I think it makes more sense to spend effort here instead of getting CMake working with all your dependencies. There are also [some projects](https://github.com/google/bazel-to-cmake) that try to make an Bazel CMake interop.

Answer (score -59):

The best way to achieve this is to eliminate your dependencies.

Dependencies are evil.

Eliminate them instead of depending on them.

Seriously.

You don't want to download them manually, you don't want to store them in your repository, your clients don't want to download them for you. In fact, your compiler doesn't even want to compile them.

Prefer switching to java to adding a C++ library dependency...

In the meantime, the suggestion to check out the [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aExternalProject) module of CMake is the closest you're gonna get to a non-repository-stored automatic-dependency-download-configure-build-and-install anytime soon with a CMake-based build.

Comment: Nope, can't do. Switching to Java? No. No. No. Please god NOOOOOOO!

Comment: I think this is an interesting point; however, it's phrased like flame bait and doesn't account for the user's needs.

Comment: I guess one man's humor is another man's "flame bait"... And I think the reference to ExternalProject, both in my answer and in the other more-upvoted answer, is the closest thing there is that does account for the user's needs. There is no magic silver bullet here; no maven for C++. If the http://ryppl.org project ever becomes a reality, it will surpass ExternalProject. For now, that's the best pointer I've got.

Comment: Upvoted. So far there are 6 people who saw the funny side and 25 who did not.

Comment: I was going to upvote it, because I also prefer efficient self-contained libraries, but then I read "Java", which is the kind of dependency I'll never accept in any project, so I'm downvoting it. If you hadn't mention Java, you'd have my upvote.

Comment: Java? Why not python and just "import solution"

Comment: I also laughed, but had to downvote due to the Java thing, and code reuse is a beautiful thing, we jut need to get better at it. Sorry Dave...

Comment: Let’s recreate sdl2 and imgui from scratch again and again